# GAE - Unable to update: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException:

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I tried to upload my test gwt app but I've just faced a quite strange error. Every time I try to upload app I get this:

> Unable to update app: Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=gwttestapp001&version=1.0&
>   500 Internal Server Error
>
> Server Error (500) A server error has occurred.
>
> See the deployment console for more details Unable to update app:
>   Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=gwttestapp001&version=1.0&
>   500 Internal Server Error
>
> Server Error (500) A server error has occurred.

... console says this

> Skipping GWT compilation since no relevant changes have occurred since
>   the last deploy. Created staging directory at:
>   'C:\DOCUME~1\1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg4973998929980348825.tmp' Scanning
>   for jsp files. Scanning files on local disk. Initiating update.
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to
>   URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=gwttestapp001&version=1.0&
>   500 Internal Server Error
>
> Server Error (500) A server error has occurred.
>
> Debugging information may be found in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\1\Local Settings\Temp\appengine-deploy1308974562331110258.log

... and error log says this:

> Unable to update: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException:
>   Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=gwttestapp001&version=1.0&
>   500 Internal Server Error
>
> Server Error (500) A server error has occurred.
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:281)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:234)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:213)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:606)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:414)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:122)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:328)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:265)
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

I just updated GAE from 1.5.2 to 1.6.2 but the error keeps going :(

How to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well... I had to make my own research of this kind of problem deeper on...
So I guess I finally found the problem root :S The thing is in my app version syntax;

My appengine-web.xml file was containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>gwttestapp001</application>
  <version>1.0</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

... but [according to tutorial I found](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#About_appengine_web_xml) the thing is "there is no way to use dots" in version spelling so I changed the content to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
      <application>gwttestapp001</application>
      <version>1</version>
    </appengine-web-app>
```

... and all uploaded successfully :)

I hope that tip saves ones day

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this can be like, as it worked for me:

properties starts

```
<appengine.app.version>10</appengine.app.version>       
<appengine.target.version>1.8.7</appengine.target.version>      
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

properties ends

configuration starts

```
<version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
```

configuration ends

In **configuration** label, write version as that in **properties** label as above. Hope this will help.