# GWT-Eclipse Deployment Error

Tags: gwt, web-deployment

Got this while deploying:

> Unable to update: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/clonefiles?app_id=venuebookingservice&version=2&
>   500 Internal Server Error

I'm using the Eclipse GWT plugin for Eclipse 3.6. It was deploying fine before this started.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198398/gae-unable-to-update-com-google-appengine-tools-admin-httpioexception

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Eclipse 3.6 with GWT. Our experience was horrible during our project(Indigo contains lots of bugs). Try to use Eclipse Juno (4.2) which is much more stable and works fine. Lots of bug /trouble will be resolved.

Comment: I suppose that would be a good thing to do, but for now, I resolved the problem by deploying into a new version. Still, I don't know what caused the problem in the first place.